# Clone, clear input and html

Tags: jquery

I have this simple snippet of code below to clone some html code.
As you can see it clears all the `inputs`.

The problem is that I have also to clear all the `spans`. I tried to add another `.find` searching for `spans` and clearing the HTML. But obviously after the first `.find` it does look into `inputs` and does not find any `span`.
How can I edit the blow code in order to clean also all the `spans` in addition to `inputs` ?

```
$('#addBox').clone(false).find("input").val('').end().appendTo('#append');
```

Comment: why not write 2 lines ? 1 for clearing the input fields, the other to clean the spans (using `html('')` instead of `val('')`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#addBox').clone(false).find("input, span").val('').html('').end().appendTo('#append');
```

See [css selectors standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) for details (paragraph `5.2.1 Grouping`)

Comment: Does not work. You cannot clean a span element with val('') you need html('')